# Woocomerce Product cateegory filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filtering, elementor

I'm building a WooCommerce site and having an issue with category product filtering. Is there a way that I can show only certain categories? I want to achieve this (see screenshot below) so the "FESTSITZENDE PROSTHETIK" is just a title and not a category which means that I want to show a title then a few categories, then another title and few categories. 
Everything I tried so far,didn't work as intended. Does anyone has any suggestions on how can I achieve the same thing like the picture? Also, can you suggest me some free plugins for product category filtering because I tried a few but they didn't work either.
[image]
Thanks

p.s im not sure if i have to mentioned that i'm building this website in elementor.

Comment: What do you mean by a few categories? Do you want to show selected categories below the title with Filter function?

Comment: The things marked with red are categories. I have products with certain categories. On my shop page I want to display a side bar like the picture above but the FESTSITZENDE PROSTHETIK, ABNEHMBARE PROSTHETIK and KIEFER ORTHOPAEDIE are not categories, just text.
I tried different plugins but when i set filter by categories it showing me all the categories i have in the sidebar. I can't find a way how to exclude and show only certain categories so I can achieve design like this. Do you get my point?